# How to dynamically adjust the height of Today Extension

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a today extension that displays both a table view and some text. I want to dynamically resize the widget so that it fits the height of the tableview.

[image]

I have tried using autolayout as well as:

```
self.preferredContentSize = self.tableview.contentSize
```

But the because my view is taller than just the tableview height it does not work.

I found a couple of example showing how to do it in Objective C but none in Swift.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: "because my view is taller than just the tableview height it does not work" So supply a `preferredContentSize` with a bigger height.

Comment: Yes but then the today extension height won't be calculated dynamically right ?

Comment: You mean something like that : self.preferredContentSize = self.tableview.contentSize + 50 ?

Comment: Maybe. You said "your view is taller". I don't know how much taller it is, but supposedly you do. So you should be able to provide the right calculation. - I appreciate that this won't be dynamic in some magic automatic sense, but surely if the height of the table changes, you'll know about it, right?

Comment: Thanks. So I am now using `self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(0), self.tableView.contentSize.height + CGFloat(50))` as you suggested. Is there a way to get the height of the gap between the top of the tableview and the top of the ViewController or will I have to settle for a constant ?

Comment: "Is there a way to get the height of the gap" I don't know what gap we're even talking about. Do you mean the dark area containing the "EU" and "GDP" labels? Surely you must be able to ascertain its height; it's your view.